# Python matplotlib.pyplot separate between plt.figure

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory

This is a simple problem, however, I couldn't figure it out!I am plotting multiple figures in Python, each having multiple sub-plots. But when plotting them, they are stacked one after another. They are plotted as separate images (when opening each figure, it is not merged with the others), but when looking at them in the output console, they seem like a single merged image (stacked one on the top of the others).

I tried to print something between the different parts of the figures to separate them, but it didn't work (all the printing happened at the start of the output, and later all the figures are plotted stacked one on the top of others!).

How can I make some space between the different figures? I am using Google Colab to write and run the code.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
for n in range(start, end) : 
     plt.subplot(4,4,n+1)
     plt.imshow(data1[n])   
     plt.axis('off')

#--
print("-----")
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
for n in range(start, end) : 
     plt.subplot(4,4,n+1)
     plt.imshow(data2[n])   
     plt.axis('off')
#--
print("-----")
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
for n in range(start, end) : 
     plt.subplot(4,4,n+1)
     plt.imshow(data3[n])   
     plt.axis('off')
```

Comment: which browser did you use

Comment: I use Opera browser.

Comment: i can see plots separately, if you have the full code, i can try with that

Answer (score 0):

Adding plt.show() after each set should work, here you go:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
for n in range(start, end) : 
     plt.subplot(4,4,n+1)
     plt.imshow(data1[n])   
     plt.axis('off')
plt.show()#Add this 

#--
print("-----")
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
for n in range(start, end) : 
     plt.subplot(4,4,n+1)
     plt.imshow(data2[n])   
     plt.axis('off')
plt.show()#Add this 

#--
print("-----")
plt.figure(figsize=(15,15))
for n in range(start, end) : 
     plt.subplot(4,4,n+1)
     plt.imshow(data3[n])   
     plt.axis('off')
plt.show()#Add this
```

Comment: I highly doubt it has anything to do with ``plt.show()``.

Comment: @Karina without plt.show(), plots/figures will be stacked on top of each other after the run is complete, in which the user will be able to see the final plot/figure only and not all the individual ones.

Comment: I just read that OP uses google colab. In that case I have no idea. In my Jupyter it works just fine

Comment: @Karina sadly it didn't work